# Can't reach Docker container from other Docker container through host IP

Tags: docker

I got a server running a Wireguard VPN on `10.0.1.254/24` and Docker is running on `172.17.0.1/16`.

My `docker-compose.yaml` looks like this (simplified):

```
services:
  container_a:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '10.0.1.254:80:80'

  container_b:
    image: alpine:latest
```

Now, I can reach nginx using `wget http://10.0.1.254` on the host. I can also reach it the same way from a VPN peer (e.g. `10.0.1.1`). But when I try to do this from within another Docker container (e.g. `docker compose exec container_b wget http://10.0.1.254`) I get a timeout. However, I can ping the host (`docker compose exec container_b ping 10.0.1.254`).

My guess is that this has something to do with the way Docker maps ports on the host. But I can't find much information about this. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: are you sure to use the right ports and the services aare running?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I still had UFW installed, which was configured to allow incoming  connection to this port on the `wg0` interface. But the system was smart enough to take a shortcut, directly from one virtual Docker interface to the other, bypassing this ACCEPT rule for the `wg0` interface.

I figured this out by using `tail +1f /var/log/ufw.log`, and then running the failing `wget` command from the other Docker container.

In my case the solution was to simply disable UFW (`sudo ufw disable`), as I'm not using it anyway.